# Metacharacters at command-line

Tags: java, regex, string, command-line-arguments

The code:

`String s = "\d";`

raises an compiler error, illegal escape character. Ok understood!!

But the code:

```
class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String s = args[0];
System.out.println(s);
}
}
```

does not when invoked with the command `java Test \d` or `java Test "\d"`. Why??

Infact it even prints: `\d` without using the double back-slashes ("\\d").

Aren't the arguments provided via command-line treated as Strings only?

I know it can't raise a *compiler error* because arguments provided at command-line are *after* compilation stage but then shouldn't it raise a *runtime exception* or something??

Or is it that once we have passed through the compilation stage it doesn't matter what the String contains (because the code is converted in bytecode and the whole code structure is altered)? If yes, then can someone please elaborate.

Thnx in advance!!

Comment: I believe the illegal escape character in a string is **just** a compiler error, is it not? So wouldn't Java go ahead and make sure it didn't have illegal escapes during runtime by itself? It's protecting you as the programmer, not you as a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't realise that shell command lines and Java are two different languages. A command line given to a shell is parsed as a shell command. A Java program given to `java` is parsed as Java.

You are possibly also confusing *strings literals* (pieces of code that produce strings) and *strings* (values consisting of a sequence of characters).

You want the two character *string* `\d` to be stored in variable `s`. You need to construct an appropriate *string literal* in order to do that.

- To produce the two character string `\d`, one can use a cmd (Windows shell) string literal `\d`.
- To produce the two character string `\d`, one can use a Java string literal `"\\d"`.

Comment: thnx.. i understood the two language stuff but i still don't get the difference b/w string literals and string. i dnt want to take much of your time so if you can guide me to an article or something about this, i will be grateful!!

Comment: @WickeD, I rearranged my post for clarity. Should help? I'll be happy to answer any questions, but I don't know of any articles on the subject.

Comment: @WickeD, String literals are necessarily different than strings because the compiler must know where the literal ends. This is usually done using quoting. But now you need a means of including the quoting character in a string. That's often done by escaping it using a backslash. But now you need a means of including backslashes in strings. That's done by escaping backslashes using another backslash. So to get a string consisting the two characters `\d`, one places the five characters `"\\d"` in the code.

Comment: ok so m guessing "\d" in `String s = "\d";` is a _string literal_ and the argument at commmand-line is a _string_. right??

Comment: Both are string literals, one for `java` and one for `cmd`. Each language has its own syntax, so it's no surprise that different literals are needed to produce the same string.

Comment: Different shells have different syntax too. You'd need `java Test \\d` if you had been a bash shell, for example. That's why I knew you were on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Doubling backslahes is only a matter of syntax. In Java code, to represent a single backslash within quotes, you must type it twice. However what you are really representing is a single backslash.

When you pass it through the command line, you do not need escaping since it is not Java code.

Comment: @polet: so basically it boils down to: "once we have passed through the compilation stage it doesn't matter what the String contains". right??

Comment: @WickeD Not really. You are manipulating all the time the value '\d'. The thing is that in Jav code, to represent that value, the syntax requires escaping and therefore you must write "\\d". In terms of String value there is absolutely no difference!

Answer (score 1):

> Aren't the arguments provided via command-line treated as Strings only?

Yes, they're strings. String *objects*. That's fine.

However, in *code*, you've got string *literals*. Those are parsed by the Java compiler to produce String *objects* at execution time. The escaping is part of the Java language, *not* part of the String objects.

(Note that some other libraries - particularly regular expressions - may *also* have their own escaping mechanisms, but fundamentally if you run

```
java Foo \d
```

then assuming your *shell* doesn't do anything funny (which will depend on that shell!) then you end up with a two character string: a backslash followed by a `d`.

Comment: "The escaping is part of the Java language, not part of the String objects." plz elaborate.. what does is means to be a part of a String object.

Comment: @WickeD: I mean that a string is just a sequence of characters. It has no concept of escape sequences. The escaping is part of how you specify a string *in Java source code*.